# Server-side form tag master page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to define a common login section on the navbar, which is saved on the master page.

My problem is, asp.net doesn't allow to have multiple tags runat = "server" per page. How can I overcome this issue, so that I can have controls on the master page (user login in navbar) and on the child pages as well?

The issue is with the button located at the bottom. I have to surround it with form runat="server" tag. But I already have 1 one form tag in the page at the very bottom for the child pages.

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="SignUp.aspx">Sign Up to the Service</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Login<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownlogin">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="usr" class="userlogininfo">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"/> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pwd" class="userlogininfo">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd"/>
                </div>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="LoggedHome.aspx" role="button">Go</a>

                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" ID="btnLogin" Text="Vai" runat="server" />

              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post a snippet from your master page & login control? And a skeleton of the respective post back handlers ?

Comment: Why not just put the form in the master page? Just have one form.

Comment: @brianchandley updated the question with a snippet of my master page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setup you have would render a form within a form, this is not allowed.

If you can:
re-imagine the markup so the forms are side by side
OR: 
If the side-by side this is not possible,try simply removing the login form tag. - the parent form tag  will post back to the same page: if this is all you want, it may do the trick.

This is  @mason suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As mason said, just put the form runat="server" tag in the master page that will enclose all your controls,
so you can add server controls anywhere inside the master or child pages & controls

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

             <snip>....</snip>
</ul>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```